# Android adb is not detecting Kogan 8'inch Tablet

Tags: adb

Android adb is not detecting my device
I installed the adb driver in windows and adb tool in tablet, then device is visible in Windows Device Manager as "Android Composite ADB Interface" but when i run command "adb devices" the list shows empty....
Im using 8inch android Tablet(Kogan) running OS is 4.1.1 and device is connected as "Media Device(MTP)". Usb Debugging Enabled.

Answer (score 1):

Check your USB cable : could happen the one you use works only for charging and not for transferring data. Read following posts [Can't find android device using "adb devices" command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6026948/cant-find-android-device-using-adb-devices-command)

Comment: As the `device is visible in Windows Device Manager` it is communicating.